# matplotlib - twinning y axis causes mismatched x-intercept

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting modelled versus measured meteorlogy data in a heatmap and using secondary axes to display alternate units.  The problem I am having is that when I twin the x and y axes I get a slight offset between y-axis 1 and y-axis 2.  It doesn't seem to matter if I use the exact same extents, or different.  The final product I would like is this without the y-axis offset:

[image]

Below is a *brief* excerpt of code that has the same issue (but is simpler):

```
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(WRF,EMS,bins = 50)
if max(yedges)>max(xedges):
    extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
else:
    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], xedges[0], xedges[-1]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, sharex=True, figsize = [10,10])
ax.imshow(heatmap,extent = extent,  origin = 'lower', interpolation = 'none', cmap = CM.gist_heat_r)
ax.set_xlim(extent[0],extent[1])
ax.set_ylim(extent[0], extent[1])
ax.tick_params(labelbottom='on',labeltop='off', labelleft="on", 
    top='off', left='on', right='off')
plt.draw()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(extent[0],extent[1])
ax2.set_xlim(extent[0],extent[1])
plt.xlim(extent[0],extent[1])
plt.ylim((extent[0],extent[1]))
```

which gives the following:
[image]

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing.  I've tried suggestions from other threads like using `plt.xlim(extent[0],extent[1]))` with no luck.

Comment: What is your definition for `extent`?

Comment: good point.  Will edit, I'm grabbing extent from the data limits from the heatmap generation.  Will add the code.

Comment: Though I found out it doesn't really matter; I copied your code, set `extent = [0, 20, 0, 20]` and get the same problem. It *is* weird, and possibly a bug in mpl.

Comment: Good to know it's reproducible.  Hopefully I'm just missing something.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I had another look at this, and I can't find a way to get rid of it, e.g. by using `ax.set_adjustable('box-forced')` (in which case the second y-axis will extent outside the graph). It does appear to work correctly when using `twiny` instead, so it feels more and more like a bug in mpl.

Comment: What I ended up doing was using a different method altogether.  Used pcolor(x,y) which actually graphs the data as opposed to plotting an image.  I didn't answer this question as it really isn't a solution.